# Button alignment issue in right-to-left form on Shopify using Liquid

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm facing an issue with aligning a button on the left side of a form in a Shopify theme. The form is in a right-to-left direction, and I'm using Liquid for template on the Shopify platform.

Here's the code structure:

```
 {%- when 'form-search' -%}
    <div dir="rtl" class="header-search js-header-search">
      <form action="/search" class="form-search">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{settings.search_type}}" name="type">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{settings.search_unavailable_result}}" name="options[unavailable_products]">
        <input type="hidden" value="last" name="options[prefix]">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="{{ 'section.header.search_placeholder' | t}}" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-{{submit_button_style | default: 1}}" test="{{submit_button_style}}">
          <span>Search</span>
          {%- render 'svg', type: 'is-loading' -%}
        </button>
      </form>
      <div class="search-results">
        <div class="search-results_wrapper">
          <div class="results">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn-view-all">
              {{- 'general.search.view_all' | t }}
              <span class="js-results-count"></span
            ></a>
          </div>
          <div class="no-result">{{ 'general.search.no_results' | t }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% comment %} end {% endcomment %}
```

To achieve the desired layout, I added `dir="rtl"` to the parent container (`<div class="header-search js-header-search">`) to set the right-to-left direction. I also applied Flexbox to the form by setting `flex-direction: row-reverse;`. However, despite these attempts, the button continues to appear on the right side of the form instead of the left.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly align the button on the left side within the form when using right-to-left direction in Shopify, specifically with Liquid and Flexbox.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!